# Using a wildcard in a sumproduct in excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find a way to use sumproduct in excel but for only the records that begin with a certain character string.

Basic sumproduct

```
=SUMPRODUCT(BC:BC,BD:BD)/SUM(BC:BC)
```

Is there any way to make each range dependent upon a search criteria?  So let's say, only use records in BC:BC & BD:BD that have a corresponding record in BA:BA that begins with Stack.  I don't think you can use wildcards in sumproduct but is there another function I could be using?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You CAN do this using sumproduct... The trick is to use the `--` operator to change `True` / `False` to `1` / `0` and then you can multiply your other columns by that vector so as to get only the rows where your statement evaluates to true

**Try this:**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(FIND("Stack",A:A))),BC:BC,BD:BD)/SUM(BC:BC)
```

To explain, the part `--(ISNUMBER(FIND("Stack",A:A)))` basically says `If the word "Stack" exists in the cell in column A, evaluate to 1, otherwise, evaluate to 0` - Then you multiply by the values in `BC` & `BD` to get your final result.

---

**One note:**

You could make this formula more efficient / faster to calculate (if you're using it A LOT in your sheet, by replacing, for example, `BC:BC` to include the maximum number of rows you want, so, for example `BC:BC` becomes `BC1:BC1000` - Therefore not having to try and calculate it for the entire column.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks!  This was exactly what I needed!  I'm only using it once in a worksheet so this works perfectly!

Comment: Glad it worked!! - Also, since you're new to SO, remember to mark this as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For `"begins with stack"` specifically you can use `LEFT` function, e.g.

`=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(BA:BA,5)="stack")+0,BC:BC,BD:BD)/SUMIF(BA:BA,"stack*"BC:BC)`

where 5 corresponds to the length of the search term `"stack"`

As John Bustos says, better to restrict your ranges for `SUMPRODUCT` - using the whole column may be slow